# Этимология слова "веверица"

Tags: этимология, история

Яркий пример морфологического переразложения - это слово *белка*. Белкой в Древней Руси называли пушного зверька с белой шерсткой (отсюда историческое деление на морфемы *бел-к-а*), а для зверька с коричневой было название *веверица*.

Каково происхождение этого слова? В случае с белкой все более-менее понятно. Но что за веверица?

И немного отвлеченный вопрос: белок-альбиносов не так много (раньше, наверно, было не слишком больше). Почему же тогда существовало отдельное название для них?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Название "белка" в других славянских языках почти неизвестно — только "веверица" в различных фонетических вариантах. В др.-рус. языке — **бѣлъка,** особенно часто с XIV века. Возможно, сначала говорили: **бѣла вѣверица,** потом — белка.

**Но почему красновато-рыжий зверек назван белым?** Такая порода могла существовать в Древней Руси. Интересна следующая запись русского путешественника (1770 год): "Между белками,  ловимыми в Камских лесах, встречаются совсем белые, которых ловцы называют **"князьями беличьего рода".**  **Далее он рассказывает о срапульском жителе Воеводском, который долго хранил шкурку такого "беличьего князька".**

Кроме того, встречается очень редкая голубая порода, которая тоже могла быть названа белой (светлой).

Материал из словаря Черных.

Answer (score 2):

Этимология, как говаривал Фасмер, тёмная.

Народ [обсуждает этот вопрос на форуме](http://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=65903.0) (неубедительно), а самая подробная информация собрана в книге "Энциклопедический мир Владимира Даля: Книга вторая".

Оная книга не копируется, даю скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У Даля веверица белая...

> ...Всячески некстати иные ученые сурка прозвали веверицей. Виру
>   платили по белей веверице или по белей векше; но это или не
>   доказывает, чтобы веверица и векша было одно и то же, а только что они
>   были в одной цене.

Answer (score 2):

Что касается "белой", то по-моему тут все очевидно, не знаю, чего там Черных мудрит. Про Даля даже задуываться серьезно не хочу, этимология у него никогда не была авторитетной.

Белым называли объект (товар, ресурс) более ценный, качественный - в противоположность черному, низкосортному. Но вершине этой цветовой иерархии стоял "красный" - самый дорогой, элитный. Для выражения "белая веверица" - вполне вариант, едва ли не абсолютный. Сравните с "черной" и "белой рыбой". К последней относили судака и некоторые другие ценные виды, а всякая мелочь считалась черной, шла только на уху. Красная - осетрина - шла в основном на стол знатных людей.

Видимо, на момент образования сочетания белка была более ценной из всех вевериц.

Само же **веверица**, как уже сказали, слово темное. Хотя можно предположить, что слово эвфемистического происхождения, аналогичное медведю, т.к. строго  ограничено славянскими,

> И немного отвлеченный вопрос: белок-альбиносов не так много (раньше,
>   наверно, было не слишком больше). Почему же тогда существовало
>   отдельное название для них?

Вот этого совсем не понял. Никаких альбиносов или отдельных названий тут не просматривается.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Под *белкой-альбиносом* я имел в виду зверька с белой шкуркой (если верить Энциклопедическому словарю юного филолога их и называли *белками*). Но ведь **белые** белки встречаются довольно редко, так? Почему же тогда для них было отдельное слово (почему их называли не веверицами?)? И каким образом тогда победил вариант *белка*?

Comment: Я понял про словарь, но я подобные источники не комментирую. А он точно "юного филолога", а не, скажу, фенолога? Никакого "отдельного слова" не просматривается.

Comment: Да нет, филолога (а в переиздании - лингвиста). Автор статьи Е. А. Земская, если интересно. Цитата: "Так произошло [переразложение] со словом *белка* - названием маленького пушного зверька. В Древней Руси было два слова для названия этого животного: *веверица* и *белка*. Последним называли зверьков с белой шкурой. В ходе истории языка слово *веверица* утратилось, и словом *белка* стали называть всех животных этого рода, независимо от их цвета. Однако белыми зверьки бывают крайне редко, поэтому внутренняя форма перестала осознаваться: связь с прилагательным *белый* утратилась".

Comment: Действительно, логичное объяснение. Производство же от всяких альбиносов несколько фантастично.

Answer (score -1):

*белка*  от белого брюха у всех разновидностей белок (красных, рыжих, черных и т.д.).

Термин *веверица* встречается в "Повесть временных лет" в 859: "Имаху дань варязи из заморья на чюди, и на словесех, на мери и на всех и на кривичех. А козари имаху на полянех, и на северех, и на вятичех, имаху по беле и *веверице* от дыма". Др.словами, норманны и хазары поделили сферы влияния в Восточной Европе. Варяги обложили данью чудь, ильменских словен, мерю и кривичей, весь, а хазары — с полян, северян, вятичей (брали с них дань по серебряной монете и *веверице* с дыма).

В современном молдавском (румынском) языке словом "веверица" называют белку. Видимо это слово заимствовано из древнерусских языков, так как до молдаван на части территории современной Молдовы жили древние славянские племена.

Викизнание

Веверица векша, белка, шкурка белки) — самая мелкая, неделимая ден. единица Др. Руси. Впервые упоминается в летописи в сер. 9 в., встречается в "Русской правде". В сев.-рус. денежной системе X — нач. XIII вв. В. равнялась 1/3 резаны, 1/6 куны; в гривне содержалось 150 вевериц.

По данным Березовского клада сер. 10 в., В. весила 0,34 г. В реальном обращении была, вероятно, двойная веверица., равная фризскому динарию. В переводных текстах термином "веверица" передается название византийской медной монеты ("нумий").

```
Лит.: Трутовский В., Векша, веверица, бела, в сб.: Труды этнографо-археологич. музея 1-го МГУ, M., 1926; Янин В. Л., Денежно-весовые системы рус. средневековья, M., 1956, с. 160-61.
```

Советская историческая энциклопедия. — М.: Советская энциклопедия . Под ред. Е. М. Жукова. 1973—1982